# C# decoding string not equal when hard code string and when use the string get from database

Tags: c#, encoding

I have the string "leave Ã¢Â€Â“ come see why", with the same code

```
string input= myString;
Byte[] latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes((input));
output= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(latin1);
```

When myString is hardcode in the program it return right value "leave - come see why". But when myString get from database it return the wrong.

Addition information: When I change the encoding of code file, the hard code version also get the wrong result, I don't know why?

The string in database and in hard code 100% the same. when I debug the Input in hardcode and Input in database is the same, Only the Output not the same :(

Comment: Is your database set up to store unicode characters correctly?  Have you inspected to see what raw string is coming back from the database - is it _definitely_ the same?

Comment: Yes it is 100% the same. when I debug to see value it still the same, Only the result not the same :(

Comment: Have you tried to compare the hardcoded string and the one from database in code?

Comment: Yes it is 100% the same. when I debug to see value it still the same, Only the result not the same

Comment: Out of curiosity, what database are you using?

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Ok. Is the data type in the database VARCHAR or NVARCHAR?

Comment: NVARchar, but  I don't think the reason is from database because When I change the encoding of code file, the hard code version also get the wrong result

Answer (score 0):

First the string is encoded into ISO 8859-1 Latin 1 (code page 28591) and then it is decoded back as Unicode (UTF-8). This will work for lower part of the character table, but probably it will not work for all characters in the higher part of the table - accents, special characters, since these characters have different byte codes in these two code pages.

The correct approach would be to use the same code page for encoding and decoding.

Comment: but both of them is the same string. When I change the encoding of code file. the hard code version also get the wrong result